# How to Process Rows of Google Sheet Singly?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, google-sheets-custom-function

I have a google sheet with the following headers:

```
| name   |  prop_id |  number | street | city | state | zip | phone | first_name | last_name | email |
|--------|:--------:|--------:|-------:|-----:|------:|----:|------:|-----------:|-----------:------:|
```

Ultimately, I want to write a custom function that will will take each row in the sheet and make a Post call to an an API to post a payload.

I want to create a JSON object from each row with the headers as the keys and the corresponding cell as the value.

I have found many solutions/resources for exporting an entire sheets into JSON but I don't want to export, I want to turn each row into a JSON a separate object and use that object as the payload to an API call.

Here's what I've tried so far to get the values from a row of a Google Sheet:

```
// get current row
function getActiveRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

  return activeRow;
}

// get data from row
function getDataRow() {  
  //Get the data to send from the spreadsheet and prep variables
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(getActiveRow(), 1, 1, 11);
  var row = dataRange.getValues();
  var headers = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0];
  var payload = {};

  return row   
}
```

When I try to apply this formula to any row after the first row (excluding headers) I get a `#NAME?` error.

Additionally, even with just working with the first row of data (after the headers) I'm trying to buildout the payload object like so:

```
payload[headers[0]] = row[0];
return payload;
```

but am not seeing anything return.

Also, what is the equivalent of console.logging when trying to debug with a google script?

Comment: To log something, use `Logger.log("...")`. You can see the log output in _View -> Logs_.

Comment: "When I try to apply this formula" ... What formula is that? Could you perhaps share a spreadsheet with us? It would be much easier to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal: See [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98105/88163)

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to apply this formula to any row after the first row (excluding headers) I get a #NAME? error

The`#NAME?` error occurs on custom functions when the custom functions use a service, in this case SpreadsheetApp, that requires authorization to run and it is not authorized yet.

To authorize your script,

1. Go to the script editor by clicking on Tools > Script editor
2. In the toolbar, click the function selector and select one function
3. Click the Run or Debug buttons.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview for further details.

> Also, what is the equivalent of console.logging when trying to debug with a google script?

For custom logging use Logger.log(data). For further details, see
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting

UPDATE:

Google added [Stackdriving Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) support to Google Apps Script so now it's possible to use the [Class console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console) for logging messages.